# Unity3D get an Object in start Method

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hey im trying to get an object which is referenced in another script (dictionary).
But when i try to get the object in the start method it seems like the dictionary isnt populated jet.
Error: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

If I run this line of code in the update method it works completely fine.

Is there an easy way to let this line run after the dictionary is populated?

Grid Manager Script

[image: Grid Manager Script Img]

Camera Movement Script

[image: Camera Movement Script Img]

Comment: [**Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: You can change the order in which scripts are initialized, so you can force Camera Movement Script to be initialized after the Grid Manager. [Link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your code snippets run in `Start`.

There is no way to predict in which order these two `Start` messages will be invoked (at least not from the user perspective).

To solve this kind of race conditions (see [Order of execution for event functions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html)).

> The Awake function is called on all objects in the Scene before any object's Start function is called.

my general thumb-rule is:

- Use [`Awake`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html)

  to initialize the component itself where it doesn't depend on values
  from other components.

  E.g. initializing your fields, filling your collections, using `GetComponent` etc to initialize references (but stop there)
- Use [`Start`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html) to then initialize things where you do depend on other components being already initialized.

  Like in your case access the collections of the other component

This usually covers most of the cases.

In your case simply converting `GridManager.Start` to `GridManager.Awake` should already solve the issue.

Where this is not enough you either can start and tweak the [Script Execution Order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html) and basically enforce a certain order in which the event methods get invoked or implement a more complex event based initialization system

Answer (score 0):

Populate the dictionary in Awake() method instead of Start(), then it would be ready by the time you need it in Start() of another script.